# How to call a Rails method from in javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new in ruby on rails, I want to call controller method from javascript

**show.html.erb**

```
<label class="switch">
  <%if @vehicle.parking%>
    <input type="checkbox" checked onchange="parkingMode(<%= @vehicle.id %>)">
  <%else%>
    <input type="checkbox" onchange="parkingMode(<%= @vehicle.id %>)">
  <%end%>
  <span></span>
</label>
```

**vehicle_controller.rb**

```
def change_parking
  vehicle = Vehicle.find(params[:vehicle_id])
  if !vehiculo.parking
    vehicle.parking = true
    vehicle.save
  else
    vehicle.parking = false
    vehicle.save
  end
end
```

**vehicle.js**

```
function parkingMode(id){
    console.log(id)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call a Rails controller method directly from within the view, you need to send a request to it.

A good way to do this is with a form:

```
<%= form_for(@vehicle) do |f| %>
  <input name="parked" type="checkbox" checked="<%=@vehicle.parked%>" />
  <input type="submit" />
<%= end %>
```

Then your controller could update the vehicle depending on whether `params[:parked]` is checked and redirect back to the same page

```
def change_parked
  @vehicle.update_column(:parked, params[:parked])
  redirect_to vehicle_path(@vehicle.id)
end
```

The benefit of this is that you don't need any JavaScript to make changes to the vehicle. However, if you want to avoid a page refresh...

To do this without a form, you will need to use JavaScript and Ajax to ping the endpoint that routes to that controller method.

So, your `parkingMode` JavaScript method could be something like (I'm using jQuery for ease here)

```
const request = $.post('/vehicles/change_parking')
request.done((response) => {
  console.log('Do something here')
})
```

This would call your controller method, which could return `JSON` as a result:

```
def change_parking
  vehicle = Vehicle.find(params[:vehicle_id])
  if !vehiculo.parking
    vehicle.parking = true
    vehicle.save
  else
    vehicle.parking = false
    vehicle.save
  end

  render json: { vehicle: vehicle }, status: 200
end
```

Then you would need to change the `checked` value of the checkbox:

```
const request = $.post('/vehicles/change_parking')
request.done((response) => {
  $('input[type="checkbox"]).attr('checked', response.responseJSON.vehicle.parked)
})
```

There's a couple of things I want to address.

Firstly, you're using an `if` statement in your view when you could simplify it to something like:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="<%= @vehicle.parked %> onchange="parkingMode(<%= @vehicle.id %>)">
```

This means that the checkbox will only be `checked` if the vehicle is parked.

Secondly, in your `change_parking` method, you only need to call `save` once

```
def change_parking
  vehicle = Vehicle.find(params[:vehicle_id])
  if !vehiculo.parking
    vehicle.parking = true
  else
    vehicle.parking = false
  end

  vehicle.save
end
```

You could also do something like `vehicle.parking = !vehicle.parking` and remove the `if` statement.

Comment: I'd agree with Carl, but if you want to go the JavaScript route, I'd suggest [Stimulus.JS](https://stimulusjs.org/). It is super easy to use once you get the hang of it.

Answer (score 0):

You **can** call a controller action using JS. But not directly. However, you can use the tools already provided by Rails to do so.

First, we render a remote checkbox:

```
check_box_field 'parking_mode_toggle', '1', false, remote: true, data: { url: '/change_parking' }
```

Even though it's not given in the [official document](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#remote-elements), if you read the [Rails UJS code](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/ad3a47759e67a411f3534309cdd704f12f6930a7#diff-d0245501177dffccc75228bb73b11b5deb16081ea06fa5b205604d0cf05cc31cR58), you'll see that the UJS driver will make the request as soon as the checkbox is ticked/un-ticked.

Then, in your controller, you can do:

```rb
def change_parking
  # TODO: Change your database state according to the +params+ received

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render js: 'parkingMode()' }
  end
end
```